# Nightwatch.js getting text fails because of empty string

Tags: testing, selector, assert, end-to-end, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to assert an element has a certain text content
[image: Browser view and debug window]
[image: Code and test output]

But the test always fails with the message:

```
Failed [equal]: ('' == 'This is a title ') - Expected "This is a title " but got: ""
```

The test is written like this:

```
browser.getText('.ui-visible .caption-expanded b',
  function(result) {
    this.assert.equal(result.value, 'This is a title ');
  }
);
```

I also tried:

```
browser.expect.element('.ui-visible .caption-expanded b').text.to.equal('This is a title ');
```

Both attempts fail with an empty string. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do just like that `.assert.containsText('name_of_your_element', 'This is a title')`